# Creating generic function for the translation of a object to a certain method

Tags: java, generics

I currently have the following problem:

I have a `Mutation` object, which has the fields: `id` and `tableName`. This object indicates a change on the MySQL server, in the table with `name = tableName` and `row_id = id`. Now, I would like to 'translate' this object to a new request to the server. With this request I like to get the updated object from the server (which has that id and is a row in the table with that tableName). I have build the following method to do requests:

```
public <T> List<T> doGet(Class<T[]> clazz, List<Parameter> parameters) throws Exception {

    StringBuilder URL = new StringBuilder(baseURL);
    String tableName = (String) clazz.getComponentType().getDeclaredField("tableName").get(null);

    URL.append(tableName+"/get");

    ...

    T[] objectsArray = new Gson().fromJson(json, clazz);

    return Arrays.asList(objectsArray);
}
```

This method is working properly, and just returns me a list of type `T`. But I would like to use this method with a variable input.

I now have build a method that returns the correct `Class` for each tableName:

```
public static <T> Class<T> tableNameToClass(String tableName) {

    if (tableName.equals("product")) {
        return Product[].class;
    }
    else if (tableName.equals("product_variant")) {
        return ProductVariant[].class;
    }
    //etc....

    return null;
}
```

But this is not working, (Cannot convert Class to Class) so I assume I do not understand the use of generics correctly.

Another problem is that when the `doGet()` method is working, I do not know how to translate the return of this method to the correct type of `List`.

```
List<SomeType> updatedObjects = doGet();
```

But here, `SomeType` is variable, and I don't know how to get this to work generically, if it is even possible. I could also build a giant if-else with every `Class` I have, but I assume this can be done with less code.

Comment: On stackoverflow, when you say "it is not working", it is a ***very good idea*** to describe exactly in what way it is not working.

Comment: Thanks Mike Nakis for the tip, I have updated my question where needed.

Comment: There we go again, "it is not working" does not help.  Have you tried `return (Class<T>)Product[].class;` ?

Comment: The rub here is that the type argument to the method is always up to the code which calls it. So say I make a bogus call like `Utils.<String[]>tableNameToClass("product")`, I've just casted a `Class<Product[]>` to a `Class<String[]>`. There isn't a way around that aspect. You could use `tableNameToClass` like an auto-cast to save characters (which is what Mike's suggestion does), but there is no static type checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that in order for this to work properly you are going to have to introduce a new entity called `Table<T>` with the `T` parameter being the class of the row.  So, you will have a `Table<Product>` and a `Table<ProductVariant>`.

Then, you will need to pass a `Table<T> table` as the first argument to your `doGet()` method, so the result will be type-safe.  Your reflection-based, [stringly-typed](http://neologisms.rice.edu/index.php?a=term&d=1&t=14876) approach is cute, but it will not work because it offers no compile-time type information.

Comment: +1 Yes. It's not even that bad. `class Table<T> { ... public static final Table<Product> PRODUCT = new Table<>("product", Product.class); }` `List<Product> x = doGet(Table.PRODUCT, pams);` A construct like `tableNameToClass` is not type-safe *and* it isn't shorter than defining e.g. generic constants.